# in Django, how to handle get() when there's no data

Tags: python, django

i have this line in Django:

```
data['Sponsor'] = models.Family.objects.get(Dependent=data['member'])
```

I know for a fact, there's either one record or no records.
but while `filter()` returns a , `get()` appears to error out.
I just need the one record if there's one.  How do I use `get()` to act like `filter()`?

Thanks.

Comment: django's .get should seriously have a way to set a default when not found or raise if not set.

Comment: I agree.  If this is a bug, I'm thinking of putting it in..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first).

```
data['Sponsor'] = models.Family.objects.filter(Dependent=data['member']).first()
```

If there are no items, it will return `None`.

Answer (score -1):

It throws a `DoesNotExist` exception if that record does not exist.
You can catch that and handle as needed.

```
try:
    data['Sponsor'] = models.Family.objects.get(Dependent=data['member'])
except Family.DoesNotExist:
    data['Sponsor'] = None
```